# I don't understand explain result of a slow query

Tags: postgresql, explain

I have a slow query (> 1s). Here is the result of an `explain analyze` on that query:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..32275.13 rows=36 width=257) (actual time=549.409..1106.044 rows=2 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (answer.lt_surveyee_survey_id = lt_surveyee_survey.id)
    ->  Index Scan using lt_surveyee_survey_id_key on lt_surveyee_survey  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.108..0.111 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 'xxxxx'::citext)
    ->  Seq Scan on answer  (cost=0.00..32266.24 rows=36 width=230) (actual time=549.285..1105.910 rows=2 loops=1)
          Filter: (lt_surveyee_survey_id = 'xxxxx'::citext)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 825315
Planning time: 0.592 ms
Execution time: 1106.124 ms
```

The `xxxxx` parts of the result are an uuid like. I did not built that database, so I have no clue right now. Here is the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
  lt_surveyee_survey.id
  -- +Some other fields
FROM lt_surveyee_survey
  LEFT JOIN answer ON answer.lt_surveyee_survey_id = lt_surveyee_survey.id
WHERE lt_surveyee_survey.id = 'xxxxx';
```

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but `Seq Scan` instead of `Index Scan` seems to suggest that `answer.lt_surveyee_survey_id` does not have an index on it so the database has to look through all records **seq**uentially which may be causing the performance issue. Just guessing, though.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you are right. You can post this as an answer :)  (FYI there were two copy of the database and one did not have index. Weird.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JOIN` is causing the performance drop according to the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output. You can see that there are 2 different lookups, one took a couple milliseconds, and the other took half a second.

The difference is indicated by the beginning of the lines: `Index Scan` and `Seq Scan`, where `Seq` is short for sequential, meaning that all of the rows had to be checked by the DBMS to process the `JOIN`. The reason why sequential scans would occur is a **missing index** on the column being checked (`answer.lt_surveyee_survey_id` in your case).

Adding an index should solve the performance issue.